# Attach image to the Messages app programatically

Tags: android, image, sms, tablet, mms

I'm develop an app use mms message of android.

Currently I can:

1. Send ssm message but not attached image by use following code:

   ```
   Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
   smsIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
   smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
   smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
   smsIntent.setData(Uri.parse("sms:" + phoneNumber)); 

   ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(smsIntent, 0);
   ```
2. Send attach image via third party app:

   ```
   Intent mmsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
   mmsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Please see the attached image");
   mmsIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, attached_Uri);

   LogUtils.debug(TAG, "extension: " + extension);

   mmsIntent.setType(extension);
   ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(mmsIntent, 0);
   ```

My problems:

1. Can't attach image to default messaging app of android.
2. How can i detect if default messaging app of android device ( such as tablet ) not exist.

So, please guild me on this problem.

Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution for 1st problem**

`Intent mmsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 mmsIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "Please see the attached image");
 mmsIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, attached_Uri);
 mmsIntent.setType("image/gif");
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mmsIntent,"Send"));`

**Solution for 2nd problem**

You don't have to worry about that, Playstore will.
If you are using sms feature you would have given permission. So your app will not be vissible in playstore for SMS featureless devices

EDIT:

To include the sender address add an additional `EXTRA` to the intent
`mmsIntent.putExtra("address","number_here");`

Comment: @Praveen Do you have idea how to attach sender number with this code?

Comment: @Praveen I already got that, but thanks a lot for replying, now I'm in new problem. I want to open mms directly without let the user to select the app. Setting the class name does not work in all phones.

Comment: @SkyWalker Can you elaborate a bit

Comment: @Praveen I don't want a app chooser. It should directly open sms app.

Comment: @SkyWalker then replace this line ` startActivity(Intent.createChooser(mmsIntent,"Send"));` with this ` startActivity(mmsIntent);`

Comment: @Praveen Now it has "Send" written with chooser. And it still asks for app chooser. The one way is to use **ACTION_SENDTO** but I'm not able to attach image with it.

Comment: @Praveen Image is not attached in Samsung galaxy